# DHTMLX java planner add control to Lightbox :DHXExternalLightboxForm-error 'cannot be resolved to a type'

Tags: java, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using the DHTMLX javaplanner. I need to modify the lightbox interface. 
i am using following code :

```
 <div class="planner" id="planner"><%= getPlanner(request) %></div>
<%@ page import="com.dhtmlx.planner.*,com.dhtmlx.planner.data.*" %>
<%!
      String getPlanner(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
       DHXPlanner s = new DHXPlanner("./codebase/", DHXSkin.TERRACE);
       DHXExternalLightboxForm box = s.lightbox.setExternalLightboxForm("custom-event-box.jsp", 640, 350);   
       box.setClassName("custom_lightbox");
}
%>
```

I am getting an error :

```
DHXExternalLightboxForm cannot be resolved to a type.
```

do i have to import some other packages.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably import also package com.dhtmlx.planner.controls.*:

```
<%@ page import="com.dhtmlx.planner.*,com.dhtmlx.planner.data.*,com.dhtmlx.planner.controls.*" %>
```